# JMeter - Access Log Sampler only firing one line of the log file

Tags: jmeter

i'm using the access log sampler from jmeter and set it up like it was descripted here: [Access Log Sampler Tutorial](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.pdf)

However when i start the test it only executes first entry of my logfile. I really don't understand this? Anyone had a similar problem? Any help is appreceated thx.

kukudas

Comment: found a solution: using SharedTCLogParser and OrderPreservingLogParser seems to fix it

Comment: seems to work also with TCLogParser when setting the repeat count higher.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that the problem is in configuration of your Access Log Sampler, make sure that:

You're using the latest version of JMeter 2.12 or 3.0 (earlier versions had some nasty bugs)
You're pointing Access Log Sampler to your access log, not to the Apache configuration file
You've configured the sampler correctly, it's recommended to use the following pattern: `^([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ ]) [([^]])] "([^"])" ([^ ]) ([^ ]) "([^"])" "([^"]*)"$`

If you cannot figure it out - update your question with your configuration.